# gunicorn won`t start corectly

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

When I try  to start gunicorn with command `gunicorn -w 3 run:app`
It crashes and gives me this error:

```
[2021-08-05 08:35:34 +0000] [71840] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 71840
[2021-08-05 08:35:34 +0000] [71840] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/flask/Unmarked/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/flask/Unmarked/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/flask/Unmarked/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/flask/Unmarked/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/flask/Unmarked/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/flask/Unmarked/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/flask/Unmarked/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'run'
[2021-08-05 08:35:34 +0000] [71840] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 71840)
[2021-08-05 08:35:34 +0000] [71838] [WARNING] Worker with pid 71840 was terminated due to signal 15
[2021-08-05 08:35:34 +0000] [71838] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2021-08-05 08:35:34 +0000] [71838] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

When I try to run the app with the normal command  `flask run` It works like a charm.

I believe it has something to do with the structure. But I am not sure because I am very new to flask, gunicorn and nginx:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xk9gD.png)

In the unmarked.py file is this code right now:

```
import requests

App = Flask(__name__)



@App.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    return render_template('welcome.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App.run()
```

How do I make gunicorn run I am clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably with the parameters you pass to `gunicorn`. `run:app` implies that it needs to take `app` from `run.py`, but in your case the `app` is located in `unmarked.py`, so you need to pass the first parameter accordingly.

Also, I suggest to rename `App -> app`, since the uppercase names are for classes in Python.

Try

```
gunicorn -w 3 unmarked:app
```

Comment: This worked perfectly fine I corrected the capital letters from App to app.